# Append path to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, for-loop

I need help in appeding the string to path. The problem here is that the path that i have declare cannot be call, instead it just give normal string value. here is my code.

```
public static string inputhistory1 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) + "\\Log\\" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+".chf";
public static string inputhistory2 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) + "\\Log\\FileExtact" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMM") + ".chf";
public static string inputhistory3 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) + "\\Log\\FileExtact" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyyMM") + ".chf";
public static string inputhistory4 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) + "\\Log\\FileExtact" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString("yyyyMM") + ".chf";

public static bool checkfile(string filename)
{
    bool same = false;

    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        string filechf = "inputhistory" + i;
        filechf = filechf;

        try
        {
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filechf))
            {
                if (line.Contains(filename))
                {
                    same = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    same = false;
                }

                }
            }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore if file does not exist.
        }

        if (same == true)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the sense of the line `filechf = filechf;`?

Comment: Path.Combine() can be used to append string to a path https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Seems you want to call the variable(inputhistory1) by string variable. If so ,see reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show off the expressiveness of LINQ, and the power of leveraging the tools available:

```
List<string> inputHistories = new List<string>
{
    inputhistory1, inputhistory2, inputhistory3, inputhistory4
};

public static bool checkfile(string filename)
{
    return inputHistories.Any(filename =>
        File.ReadLines(filename).Any(line => line.Contains(filename)));
}
```

Comment: maybe @jejakakhai Jk  wants to retrieve value from the variable while using string

Comment: @TommyLike: I can't read his mind. I just created code to duplicate what he posted. I have to assume that if he wanted something different, he would have asked for it.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you assign variable `filechf` with string `"inputhistory" + i`.
Use an array or list to store input history value.

```
public static string inputhistory1 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) + "\\Log\\" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+".chf";
public static string inputhistory2 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) + "\\Log\\FileExtact" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMM") + ".chf";
public static string inputhistory3 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) + "\\Log\\FileExtact" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyyMM") + ".chf";
public static string inputhistory4 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]) + "\\Log\\FileExtact" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString("yyyyMM") + ".chf";

List<string> inputHistories = new List<string>();
inputHistories.Add(inputhistory1);
inputHistories.Add(inputhistory2);
inputHistories.Add(inputhistory3);
inputHistories.Add(inputhistory4);
```

Then you could access its value by index:

```
public static bool checkfile(string filename)
    {
        bool same = false;
        //try
        //{
        for (i = 0; i < inputHistories.Count; i++)
        {
            string filechf = inputHistories[i];
            try
            {
                foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filechf))
                {

                    if (line.Contains(filename))
                    {
                        same = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        same = false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
              //ignore if file does not exist
            }
            if (same == true)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Index should start from 0

Answer (score 0):

There are kinds of solutions may meet your requirements

1. you can store the variables in a dictionary:

   ```
   var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
   dictionary.Add("inputhistory1", inputhistory1);
   dictionary.Add("inputhistory2", inputhistory2);
   dictionary.Add("inputhistory3", inputhistory3);
   dictionary.Add("inputhistory4", inputhistory4);
   //use as below
   Console.WriteLine(dictionary["inputhistory1"]);
   ```
2. or you can use reflection, for more information [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx):

   ```
   public class TestClass
   {
       public static string inputhistory1 = "value1";
       public static string inputhistory2 = "value2";
       public static string inputhistory3 = "value3";
       public static string inputhistory4 = "value4";
   }        
   var obj = new TestClass();
   var field = typeof (TestClass).GetField("inputhistory1");
   //use as below
   Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(obj));
   ```
3. even you can use switch/case to return your variable value